# Difference between Angular and Jquery ajax request methods

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm just starting out with Angularjs and I'm trying to do everything "the Angular way" but am having trouble binding some behavior to a standard web form. The form is created by rails' `form_for` method and thus sprinkles in some magic like the csrf inputs in addition to the inputs that are hand coded.

After struggling with the `$http` method native to Angular, I switched to jQuery's `$.ajax` method and discovered that I was on the correct trajectory but am not implementing the method correctly. I can't figure out my implementation error.

**Example:**

```
var checkList = angular.module('checkList', [])                                 

checkList.directive('formSubmit', function($http) {                             
  return {                                                                      
    restrict: 'A',                                                              
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {                                        
      elem.bind('click', function() {                                           
        console.log(elem.serialize());                                          
        $.ajax(attrs.action + ".json", {                                        
          data: elem.serialize(),                                               
          method: attrs.method,                                                 
          complete: function(data) {                                            
            console.log(data);                                                  
          }                                                                     
        });
        // **THE ABOVE CODE WORKS**
        // **THE CODE BELOW RETURNS THE ERROR**
        //$http({method: attrs.method,                                          
              //url: attrs.action + ".json",                                    
              //data: elem.serialize()}).                                       
          //success(function(data, status, headers, config) {                   
                //console.log(data);                                            
          //}).                                                                 
          //error(function(data, status, headers, config) {                     
                //console.log(data);                                            
          //})                                                                  
      });                                                                       
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
});
```

The error I get is in the rails console (the browser console doesn't output much) is: `MultiJson::LoadError (795: ...`

Given the error, I'm assuming it has something to do with serialization of the form. However, reading through the documentation of both jQuery and Angular, it's not clear what is different about the serialization technique AND outputting `elem.serialize()` to the console prior to submitting the form yields the same string for both the jQuery and Angular approach.

Note that I appreciate the 'right' way to do this would be to bind the form inputs to an Angular model, but I believe I'm prevented from doing this because of the additions rails makes to the form.

Why does the jQuery method work and the Angular method fails?

Comment: It's actually tough to use a templating language like ERB.  Generally, Agnular works best with "straight" HTML.  As your comment states, you know the 'angular way' would be to bind the form elements to a model and the controller method that does work to the submit button.  I'm rusty on rails, but isn't there a way to pass arbitrary html attributes to the markup for elements?

Comment: whoops, just edited to show the error.